# Edge extension force installation through the registry

Tags: microsoft-edge-extension

Updating the windows registry in order to force install an Edge extension didn't work for me.
the goal is to install the extension NOT from the Edge add-ons store. but from a web server through an update.xml file.

I've tried to update the windows registry in order to force the installation of an Edge extension.
I tried all documented ways available on the internet in order to achieve that.
but non of the ways worked for me.

is there anyone out there that knows how to do it the right way to really works?

Comment: How do you set the registry settings to force install the extension? Please provide an example which can reproduce the issue. Besides, please note that *For Windows instances not joined to a Microsoft Active Directory domain, forced installation is limited to apps and extensions listed in the Microsoft Edge Add-ons website*. You can refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/DeployEdge/microsoft-edge-policies#extensioninstallforcelist).